# R cannot use hist() because "content not numeric" due to negative decimal numbers?

Tags: r, decimal, histogram, numeric

I am new to R and I am trying to draw a histogram using hist() of a list of 100,000 numbers like this

```
-0.764
-0.662
-0.764
-0.019
0.464
0.668
0.464
```

but I cannot do it because R complains that the content is not numeric. This is what I've tried:

- I read the file using `t <- read.table(file= "file.txt", sep = "\n", dec = ".", header = TRUE)`, the data loads and looks well (I get the same values)
- I tried to make it numeric using `as.numeric(c(t[,1])), sapply(t, as.numeric)`, but I get completely different numbers, like

  53  428  791  428  582  428  979  428  456  533  550

I think their might be a problem with the decimal point "." or the negative signs "-" or both. 
Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the data. What gives `class(t[,1])` ?

Comment: It gives: [1] "factor" Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what I thought. You have to understand why R sees it as a factor. There should be something in this column (a letter, a symbol or whatever)...

Answer (score 2):

R seems to have transformed the first column of your data as a factor. This should not happen if all your data in this column where numeric in your file. So there must be an element which is not recognized as a number.

You can try the following (which is a bit dirty) in R to try to identify where the problem is. Starting with the following factor :

```
R> v <- factor(c("0.51", "-0.12", "0.345", "0.45b", "-0.8"))
```

You can identify which value causes problem with :

```
R> v[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(v)))]
[1] 0.45b
```

And you can find the position of this value in your vector with :

```
R> which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(v))))
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a factor to a numeric type, you have to understand how factors work.

Internally, each distinct item (each "factor") in a column of class `factor` is stored as a number. These are the numbers that you're seeing when you run `as.numeric`. These numbers, are actually just indexes on the levels of the factor, so if you type `levels(t[,1])` you should see a list of all the different values in the first column of your data frame.

So, with this knowledge, we can use a trick to extract the actual numbers:

```
as.numeric(levels(t[,1])[t[,1]])
```

Of course, if R interpreted this row of numbers as a factor when `read.table` was reading it, before this trick will work, you'll have to remove the row that contains the non-numeric type.